# Is there full list of Ouroboros mini-protocols that the node supports (preferably official and kept up to date)?

Tags: cardano-node

A paper from 2019 I found that describes mini-protocols: https://hydra.iohk.io/build/1070091/download/1/network.pdf. Have more protocols been added?

Answer (score 3):

The network specs used for creation of that document (updated version from 2019) lives in [ouroboros-network](https://github.com/input-output-hk/ouroboros-network/) repository, and you can find the latest CI build of the document [here](https://hydra.iohk.io/job/Cardano/ouroboros-network/native.network-docs.x86_64-linux/latest/download/2)

Comment: Following from the github repo, the main technical overview is in the "The Shelley Networking Protocol" pdf here: https://hydra.iohk.io/build/20405228/download/2/network-spec.pdf#chapter.3, and a lighter overview in the Cardano documentation here https://docs.cardano.org/explore-cardano/cardano-network/networking-protocol (need to scroll down, couldn't link to appropriate subsection)

Comment: Documentation link is dead.

Comment: It's here now https://input-output-hk.github.io/ouroboros-network/pdfs/network-spec/network-spec.pdf